# MySQL: select correlating rows

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have** `big_table` with about hundred of million rows, and `correlation_table` about few thousands of rows. `Corelation_table` correlates the rows of `big_table` to one another by `dep_id` field value.

**I want** Select all ids of correlating rows form `big_table`.

**Example:**

```
       big_table
id     name     dep_id  <other_data>
341  "vehicle"    6       .....
342   "byce"      19      .....
343  "ferrari"    6       .....

correlation_table
dep_id1 dep_id1
   6      19

expected result:
id1 id2     
341 342
343 342
```

**Question:** *how to do that in the most effective way in MySQL?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the big table twice to the correlation table by giving it two different aliases, like this:

```
SELECT
  b1.id AS id1,
  b2.id AS id2
FROM
  big_table b1
  INNER JOIN Correlation_table c ON c.dep_id1 = b.id
  INNER JOIN big_table b2 ON b2.id = c.dep_id2
```

But if you want to select all these records from a hundred million row table, this might take a while. But I don't think there's a more effective way than this.

Indexes *might* help, but hardly if you are going to select all records. The order of the joins might help a little, so you can start with the correlation table and see if that is faster:

```
SELECT
  b1.id AS id1,
  b2.id AS id2
FROM
  Correlation_table c
  INNER JOIN big_table b1 ON b.id = c.dep_id1
  INNER JOIN big_table b2 ON b2.id = c.dep_id2
```

It depends on the exact numbers. Are all rows in the big_table connected or not, are you going to select all of them, or not, how many 'groups' (dep_ids) are there, etcetera.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select b1.id, b2.id  from big_table b1 join correlation_table on depl_id = dep_id1 join big_table b2 on dep_id1 = b2.bep_id
```

It should join the tables together

Answer (score 0):

Indexing the `dep_id` column would definitely be a must. However, I don't understand why you have that column in the first place. Your "expected result" shows the structure of a cross table that relates one `big_table` entry with another `big_table` entry using the primary keys (already indexed) rather than any other value. The key field has the additional benefit of being Unique, while the `dep_id` field cannot. That should speed up searches by some amount.

To relate a `big_table` entry to another `big_table` entry, there is no way around the fact that you have to join the table with itself: `cross_table join big_table join big_table`. But don't let the fact that `big_table` has a hundred million rows concern you. If your cross table entries refers to fields that are indexed and unique, `big_table` will be accessed only with index seeks rather than index (or table) scans. So the size of `big_table` will not really be a factor. You will notice that, if you filter the query to limit the search (`where t1.id = 341` or `where t1.id in( a, small, list )`), the response will be near instantaneous.